# sed command to delete block of lines (above & below) matching a pattern (sed) - Reolved using Python

Tags: awk, sed

Refer below link

[Python script to delete json objects from json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64045853/python-script-to-delete-json-objects-from-json-file/64046063#64046063)

Since I am new to "sed",
I have a file (my_file.json) has contents as below; and I need to delete all the lines starting from "{" up to "},".

```
[
            {
                "use":"abcd",
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"my_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             },
            {
                "use":"abcd"
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"some_other_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             },
            {
                "use":"apqwkndf",
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"my_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             },
            {
                "use":"kjdshfjkasd",
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"my_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             }
]
```

I used following command ; it helps me to delete the lower portion of the block i.e. after the pattern till "}," and the line that has pattern and a line above it.

```
sed -i '/my_script.py"/I,+2 d;$!N;/my_script.py"/!P;D' my_file.json
```

and output comes out as below

```
[
            {
                "use":"abcd",

            {
                "use":"abcd"
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"some_other_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             },
            {
                "use":"apqwkndf",

            {
                "use":"kjdshfjkasd",

]
```

Expected output is; please note since it has only one block remaining so I need to remove "," as well.

```
[
            {
                "use":"abcd"
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"some_other_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             }
]
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Please add your expected output.

Comment: Added the expected output

Comment: @Abhishek, if this is a json file then experts advise on SO to parse json with a tool which knows jason well how to parse. Are you allowed to use tools like `jq`? Or you have it in your system?

Comment: No I can not use jq

Comment: `Since I am new to "sed"` Then don't use it. There are other better tools. For json use json aware tools. You can't use `jq`? Use `python` or `perl`.

Comment: Can you give me some python script to get the expected output?

Comment: ? it's just like `import json for i in json.loads(the_file): if (i['name'] 1= 'my_script.py') print(i)`.

Comment: Your `my_file.jon` is not json, you have dots after elements.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/{/{:a;N;/}/!ba;/my_script\.py/d}' file |
sed 'N;/]/s/},/}/;P;D'
```

This removes unwanted list elements then fixes up the last list delimiter.

An alternative is to store the edited file in memory and then fix up the last delimiter:

```
sed '/{/{:a;N;/}/!ba;/my_script\.py/d};H;$!d;x;s/.//;s/\(.*}\),\(\s*]\)/\1\2/' file
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following in a single `awk`, fair warning Input_files like json should be edited or read by `jq` like tools, since OP is saying he is NOT allowed to use that, so adding this. Its completely written by shown samples only.

```
awk '
/{/{
  found=1
  if(noPrint==""){
    actualVal=(actualVal?actualVal ORS:"")val
  }
  val=noPrint=""
}
found && /"name":"my_script.py"/{
  noPrint=1
}
{
  val=(val?val ORS:"")$0
}
END{
  if(noPrint==""){
    actualVal=(actualVal?actualVal ORS:"")val
  }
  sub(/},$/,"}\n]",actualVal)
  print actualVal
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way such problems are approached:

1. Package input. Typically convert to one contained information per line.
2. Filter the input.
3. Output.

The following script:

```
cat <<EOF |
[
            {
                "use":"abcd",
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"my_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             },
            {
                "use":"abcd",
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"some_other_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             },
            {
                "use":"apqwkndf",
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"my_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             },
            {
                "use":"kjdshfjkasd",
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"my_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             }
]
EOF
sed -n '
    b noterror ; : error {
        s/.*/ERROR: &/
        q1
    } ; : noterror

    # remove [ ]
    1d;$d;
    # first line should be open braces
    /{/!{b error}

    # read up until closing brackets
    # Note escaping is not handled
    : again {
        N;
        $b error
        /}/!b again
    }
    s/}.*/}/;
    s/\n/ /g;
    # -- one information per line --
    p
' | awk '
# filter that myscript.py with a regex
!/"name" *: *"my_script.py"/{
    # output with those [ ]
    printf "[\n"
    print # print the line
    printf "]\n"
}'
```

outputs:

```
[
            {                 "use":"abcd",                 "contact":"xyz",                 "name":"some_other_script.py",                 "time":"11:22:33"              }
]
```

You may want to restore newlines by placing a special character in place of a newline and then replacing that character back for a newline, or using a different delimiter for `awk`
to.