# Handle index position in Python script to delete json objects from json file - Resolved

Tags: python, json

I have a file (my_file.json) has contents as below;

```
[
            {
                "use":"abcd",
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"my_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             },
            {
                "use":"abcd"
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"some_other_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             },
            {
                "use":"apqwkndf",
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"my_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             },
            {
                "use":"kjdshfjkasd",
                "contact":"xyz",
                "name":"my_script.py",
                "time":"11:22:33"
             }
]
```

I used following python code to delete the objects that has "name":"my_script.py",

```
#!/bin/usr/python

impoty json

obj = json.load(open("my_file.json"))

index_list = []

for i in xrange(len(obj)):
     if obj[i]["name"] == ["my_script.py"]
      index_list.append(i)

for x in range(len(index_list)):
      obj.pop(index_list[x])

open("output_my_file.json","w".write(json.dumps(obj, indent=4, separators=(',',': ')))
```

but it seems I am stuck, because after popping an index the index position in actual obj gets changed, which leads to wrong index deletion or sometimes pop index gets out of range. Any other solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try popping in reverse order:

```
for x in reversed(range(len(index_list))):
```

Answer (score 0):

This will create a new list and assign only those without `"name": "my_script.py"` to the new list.

```py
obj = [i for i in obj if i["name"] != "my_script.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json
with open('my_file.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

data = [item for item in data if item.get('name') != 'my_script.py']

with open('output_my_file.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(data, f, indent=4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    import json

    json_file = json.load(open("file.json"))

    for json_dict in json_file:
        json_dict.pop("name",None)
    print(json.dumps(json_file, indent=4))
```

You don't need the last line where it says 'json.dumps' I just have it there so it looks more readable when printed.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, you usually don't want to ever change an iterable while iterating over it.
I suggest you save the elements you *do* want in the first loop:

```
import json

with open('path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

items_to_keep = []
for item in data:
    if item['name'] != 'my_script.py':
        items_to_keep.append(item)

with open('path/to/file', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(items_to_keep, f, ...)
```

The filtering can be reduced into a single line (called list-comprehension)

```
import json

with open('path/to/file', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)

items_to_keep = [item for item in data if item['name'] != 'my_script.py']

with open('path/to/file', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(items_to_keep, f, ...)
```